# Change JWT to Cookie authentication when use WebView through application

Tags: android, asp.net, authentication, cookies, webview

We have a large site that use cookie for authentication. We're going to have a simple android application for site with little features. The application use JWT for authetication.

We want the application to use through webview to access the site`s full features. When User run the application, first authenticate is done.

**Problem:** I want when user route to webview from the application change from JWT to Cookie authentication. Is this possible? If you can help?

Site develop by asp.net core 2.0;

Comment: You can decrypt the JWT on the server side and generate a cookie? You probably need an extra layer for this to check if this is nescesary.

Comment: @mohammad Akbari, Detect the calling agent. ( whether its app or browser ) and based on that decrypt jwt token and generate cookies that site requires.